# Connect By query with recurring hierarchical checks

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hierarchy, connect-by

I have written the following query and unfortunately it does not work. All I am trying to achieve is that the dates that I select with each row is the effective date of the customer relationship.

The `ci_per_per` table contains the following columns:

`per_id1`, `per_id2`, `start_dt`, `end_dt`

`per_id1` is the parent, `per_id2` is the child.

`start_dt` and `end_dt` define the duration of the relationship

```
SELECT
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT per_id2                                                           AS per_id2,
  per_id1,
  (CASE WHEN start_dt < (PRIOR start_dt1)
            THEN (PRIOR start_dt1) 
            ELSE start_dt 
        END) AS start_dt1,
  (CASE WHEN end_dt > (PRIOR end_dt1) 
             THEN (PRIOR end_dt1) 
             ELSE end_dt 
        END)         AS end_dt1,
  level                                                                             AS "PER_LEVEL"
  FROM ci_per_per
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2
```

The error I am getting for the sql is: `END_DT1: Invalid identifier.`

Is there a way to achieve this functionality in oracle?

Example scenario:

```
per_id1 | per_id2 |   start_dt  |   end_dt
-------------------------------------------
B       |   A     |  01-01-2011 | 01-01-2011
C       |   B     |  01-01-2010 | 01-01-2010
E       |   B     |  01-01-2011 | 01-01-2014
D       |   C     |  01-01-2009 | 01-01-2015
```

now I want all the records to be having `01-01-2011` as thier start date. However, if the hierarchy is reversed(meaning exchange per_id_1 and Per_id2 values), then the records should be displayed as they are.

Note that for the above example, we need to run it with the `start with` clause with `per_id2='A'` condition. Also, understand that the results might change if you run the query with the `per_id2='B'`

Thus, when I start with `per_id2='B'` the result should make all the records to be `01-01-2010` and not `01-01-2011`

now with the end date, it should be `01-01-2011` for all records except the one with E and the one with A. where the end date will be `null` (assuming we start with A).

Comment: I suspect you'll have to use recursive sub-query factoring (a recursive CTE) in order to achieve this.

Comment: can you please elaborate with some details? thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to get the lowest start and end dates within the hierarchy?

Comment: Still not totally clear what you want.  What if, in your example, the second row (C/B) was 01-01/2013?  Do you want the highest value *anywhere* in the hierarchy, or the highest below the current level?

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for asking, I want the highest value below the current level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying to work out the solution to this problem and have found a solution.

Please correct me if you think there is any issue with this below SQL:

```
select *
  from (SELECT root as per_id2,
               per_id1,
               PER_LEVEL,
               (case
                 when max(connect_by_root start_dt) >= max(start_dt) then
                  max(connect_by_root start_dt)
                 else
                  max(start_dt)
               end) as max_start,
               (case
                 when min(connect_by_root end_dt) <= min(end_dt) then
                  min(connect_by_root end_dt)
                 else
                  min(end_dt)
               end) AS min_end
          FROM (SELECT connect_by_root per_id2 AS root,
                       per_id1,
                       per_id2,
                       level as per_level,
                       (case
                         when connect_by_root start_dt >= start_dt then
                          connect_by_root start_dt
                         else
                          start_dt
                       end) as start_dt,
                       (case
                         when connect_by_root end_dt <= end_dt then
                          connect_by_root end_dt
                         else
                          end_dt
                       end) as end_dt
                  FROM ci_per_per
                CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2)
        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2
               and PRIOR root = root
         GROUP BY per_id1, per_id2, root, per_level)
 where max_start <= min_end
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56f7d/69) for the same

Answer (score 1):

A combination of an Oracle Hierarchy and CTE will produce the result you want:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 
  per_id1,
  max(connect_by_root start_dt) as max_start,
  min(connect_by_root end_dt) as min_end
FROM 
  ci_per_per
CONNECT BY 
  NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2
GROUP BY 
  per_id1)
SELECT
  ci_per_per.per_id1,
  ci_per_per.per_id2,
  cte.max_start,
  cte.min_end
FROM
  cte
  join ci_per_per on cte.per_id1=ci_per_per.per_id1
```

See [SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56f7d/9/0)  Your example is fairly simple, so I can't be certain that this logic will work for all of your test cases.

**EDIT** updated for lowest `end_dt`.

Comment: Nicely done, but If you see the select columns from my query, then you will understand that there is a connect by root in it. also, there can be multiple children for one parent for different date ranges(however, only one relationship would be active at any particular time)

Comment: Can you update  question with the additional scenarios and what the expected result should be?

Comment: Updated answer for `end_dt`.

Comment: Using `start with per_id1='A'` doesn't make sense since A is at the top of the hierarchy -- no rows will be produced.  See here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56f7d/10/0

Comment: actually A is at the bottom of the hierarchy. and I have mentioned `per_id2='A'`. Maybe this Fiddle might help you: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56f7d/15